# ssl socket multithreaded server exception

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, ssl

I want to create an ssl socket for a multithreaded server, but when a second client is connected I get some exceptions.

Here is my server code:

```
public class Master implements Runnable{

    public static SSLSocket sslSocket = null;
    public static SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket =null;
    public static SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory ;

   Master(SSLSocket s) {
      this.sslSocket = s;
   }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Listening");
    sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
    sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(7777);


   while (true) 
   {

        sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslServerSocketfactory.getSupportedCipherSuites());       
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "Master_keystore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passwd1");

        System.out.println("Connected");
        new Thread(new Master(sslSocket)).start();

    }
 }
public void run() {
   synchronized(this){
         do{
               try{      
        //here is the error
                ObjectOutputStream  objout = new ObjectOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream  objin = new ObjectInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());

                /* code */

            } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Master.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}

        }while(true);
      }
   }

}
```

And my client code is the following

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("localhost", 7777);
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslsocketfactory.getSupportedCipherSuites());  
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "Client_keystore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passwd2");
 try {
        do {
            ObjectOutputStream  objout = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream   objin = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
              /* code*/
      } while (true);


  } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

The exceptions I get are:

```
SEVERE: null
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown:                 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1553)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:247)
at master.Master.run(Master.java:233)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1035)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:738)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:221)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
... 5 more
```

can someone give me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static SSLSocket sslSocket = null;
```

The problem is here. There is absolutely no reason for making this variable `static`. Don't use `static` unless you know exactly why you are doing so.

Comment: if i remove static, I cant compile the project because I get compile error 
**non-static variable sslSocket cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: So you need to make the variable local in `main()`. You need to understand the meaning of error messages, not just apply bandages and tourniquets to them.